# Magento 2 Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3

Magento 2.3 version
In admin pages,i am getting this error -

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

    Uncaught Error: Script error for: tinymce
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
        at makeError (require.js:166)
        at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)
```

i checked other magento same questions like this but not getting actual results.

Did any one face this type of issues and How can we solve this ?

Comment: I have facing same issue. I am using old version TinyMCE that's why I am facing this issue. I have changed old to new tinymce4 and it's working now.